# How to connect celery to rabbitmq in django from docker

Tags: python, django, docker, rabbitmq, celery

I learn docker and don't understand why celery can't connect to rabbitmq. I've created 2 images for rabbitmq and django, here is my docker-compose:

```
version: "3.0"

services:
  # WEB
  django:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - media_volume:/website/journal_website/media
      - static_volume:/website/journal_website/static
      - database_volume:/website/journal_website/database
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - rabbit
  
  # RabbitMQ
  rabbit:
    hostname: rabbit
    container_name: rabbitmq
    image: rabbitmq:3.12-rc-management
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=simple_user
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=simple_password
    ports:
      # AMQP protocol port
      - "5672:5672"
      # HTTP management UI
      - "15672:15672"
    restart: always
      

volumes:
  media_volume:
  static_volume:
  database_volume:
```

my broker configuration in `settings.py` in django:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://localhost:5672'
```

`celery.py` file:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os

from celery import Celery


os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "website.settings")
celery_application = Celery("website")
celery_application.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")
celery_application.autodiscover_tasks()
```

`entrypoint.sh` that's used as entrypoint in `Dockerfile`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Start Celery
celery -A website worker -l info

# Run Django server
python3.11 manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000
```

and `Dockerfile`:

```
# Many many commands to install python and all dependencies in ubuntu 20.04

# Run Django server
EXPOSE 8000
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

I use Docker Desktop on Windows 10, when I run `docker compose up` or run container in desktop application I get such error: `[Date: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.`, I've checked that `localhost` is `127.0.0.1`. What should I do to run celery properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have to change your url to:
amqp://rabbit:5672